# my onChange event is not working on input elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component called Resume.js in which I define a function called handleChange which takes in an input paramater and based on that input value it changes my global state.

Resume.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import PersonalInfo from './PersonalInfo'
import { useState } from 'react'

const Resume = () => {

    const [resumeStates, setResumeStates] = useState({
        step: 1,
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
        email: '',
        phone: '',
        address: '',
        linkedIn: '',
        jobTitle: '',
        city: '',
        employer: '',
        startDate:'',
        endDate: '',
        responsibilities: ''
    })

    const nextStep = () => {
        const {step} = resumeStates
        setResumeStates({
            step: step+1
        })
    }

    const prevStep = () => {
        const {step} = resumeStates
        setResumeStates({
            step: step-1
        })
    }

    const handleChange = input => e => {
        setResumeStates({[input]: e.target.value})
    }
```

I am passing this handleChange function as props to a component called PersonalInfo.js as such:

```
return (
                <PersonalInfo nextStep={nextStep} handleChange={handleChange} values={values}/>
            )
```

In PersonalInfo.js I am using that prop as an onChange for my input fields:

```
import React from 'react'

const PersonalInfo = ({nextStep, handleChange, values}) => {

    const continue_step = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        nextStep()
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="container-lg w-50 rounded p-3 mt-5 ">
                <h2 className="mb-3">Personal Details</h2>
                <form>
                    <div className="mb-3 row">
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="fname" className="form-label">First Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" className="form-control" id="fname" value={values.firstName} onChange={() => handleChange('firstName')}/>
                            <div className={`text-danger fw-bold ${alert ? 'hidden': ''}`}>This is a required field</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="mb-3 row">
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="lname" className="form-label">Last Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" className="form-control" id="lname" value={values.lastName} onChange={() => handleChange('lastName')}/>
                            <div className={`text-danger fw-bold ${alert ? 'hidden': ''}`}>This is a required field</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

But my onChange for my input fields is not working as I cannot type anything in my input as a results my states do not change.

I would appreciate any kind of help...

Thank you for your time and attention.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing something called `values` to the component for the input values, but I don't see it defined anywhere.  It looks like it the values should just be the state object, so pass that:

```
<PersonalInfo nextStep={nextStep} handleChange={handleChange} values={resumeStates}/>
                                                                      ^-- here --^
```

Additionally, you're removing all of your state values any time you set one:

```
setResumeStates({[input]: e.target.value})
```

Unlike the `setState` operation in older class-based components, the set operation in the `useState` hook *does not* determine the difference for you and only update the new parts.  It replaces the state with the new state entirely.  Make sure you keep the existing state when updating it:

```
setResumeStates({ ...resumeStates, [input]: e.target.value })
```

The same will need to be done for your other state updates as well.

And finally, you're not passing the actual change event to the change handler.  Only the `title`.  You can pass the change event to the function returned by the function of the change handler:

```
onChange={e => handleChange('firstName')(e)}
```

Or [potentially] more simply:

```
onChange={handleChange('firstName')}
```

This might be getting a little confusing though and is likely to result in bugs.  (After all, it already has.)  Instead of the function within a function, just accept both arguments in the `handleChange` function:

```
const handleChange = (input, e) => {
  setResumeStates({...resumeStates, [input]: e.target.value})
}
```

And pass them both:

```
onChange={e => handleChange('firstName', e)}
```

As an aside, to help you with design-time validation of what's being passed to what functions, you might try making use of TypeScript in your React development.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you're doing a funception here.

```
    const handleChange = input => e => {
        setResumeStates({[input]: e.target.value})
    }
```

This is a "function" that returns a "function that updates state". What you need is to bind a "function that updates state" to "onChange"

---

So you can try one of these.

First way, just declare a function that receive input event normally.

```
const handleChange = e => {
   setResumeStates({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})
}

<input
  type="text"
  name="firstName"
  value={values.firstName}
  onChange={handleChange}
/>
```

or if you are feeling func-ky and wanna do func-ception. You can bind onChange with `handleChange('firstName')`.
Note that "handleChange('firstName')" will return a function that accept "e" as parameter.

```
const handleChange = input => e => {
   setResumeStates({[input]: e.target.value})
}

<input
  type="text"
  value={values.firstName}
  onChange={handleChange('firstName')}
/>
```